# Jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu theming

Tags: android, slidingmenu

i've an issue about API<=10 runtime theme switch using [jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

onCreate is like this

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTheme(themeA);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(context);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.config_sliding_menu);
```

and onButtonClick i do something like this

```
... themeA=newTheme ....
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
```

all work fine with API>10 (config_sliding_menu and main layouts after "restart" appear with newTheme ) but with API<=10 config_sliding_menu appear with default app theme defined in styles.xml and main layout appear with newTheme.

There is a way to force SlidingMenu menu on API<10 to take newTheme?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using setTheme() in your code is discouraged, see [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394).

Instead, declare the theme in your app's manifest.

```
<application
...
android:theme="@style/themeA" >
```

Comment: Thx for reply, but i need to switch themes runtime ... all work fine with API>=11

Comment: If you want i can make minimal code to reproduce the issue :D

Comment: Try calling setTheme() before super.onCreate()

Comment: Wowowowowowowowwo THHXXXXX work's fine!!!! Can you explain me why? is a workaround? I appreciate that !!!! :D

Comment: You basically need to set up the theme before any of the UI components are drawn. Glad it worked for you!